# Do the different skills on the skill tree add to each other?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In the bounty hunter: powertech skill tree, the skill puncture lets rail shot ignore up to 60% of your opponents armour and the skill superheated rail let you ignore 30% of your oppenents armour.  So does the combination of these two skills mean that you are ignoring 90% of your opponents armour with each shot? or does the game calculate the values some other way?

Comment: How far down the trees are each of these skills?  They may have intentionally made it so that you cannot have both skills at once.

Comment: one is a first level the other is five tiers up the other tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought the answer was 72% (1-(1-.6)*(1-.3)), but all the sources I find seem to suggest that 90% is the correct reduction.

Citations: [1](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=51075),[2](http://connectitall.net/cgi-bin/showthread.py?s=11e5c44446b9a93c07c83a99a4be8936&t=720194),[3](http://www.swtor.com/fr/community/showthread.php?t=44299)